# Node.js sleeps when not in use and takes a long period of time to respond initially

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have deployed Node.js as a solution to return data from the database for a React single page application. The solution works like a charm and everything is good. However what I find happening (and cannot find a solution for) is that the Node.js seems to go to sleep when not utilized after a couple of minutes. Once React site is then 'activated' again - a page loaded that requires database access, the Node.js seems to wake up and return the data, this takes a minute or two to happen. It then functions as supposed to by serving further calls in a timely manner.

Solutions online talk about Windows machine going to sleep but this is not the case here as I am connected to the machine at the time. Even if deployed locally on my development Windows 10 machine it is faster to stop and restart the Node server rather than to wait for it to respond.

The development and production machines are Windows 10 based machines with 64Gigs of Ram utilizing Mysql database.

I have not been able to find other solutions for this issue.

Below is the App.js (or server.js) file for Node to launch the server and listen to the port 3002 for incoming requests:

```
const express = require("express");
const ipfilter = require('express-ipfilter').IpFilter
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());

// Whitelist the following IPs
const ips = ['localhost']

// parse requests of content-type: application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// parse requests of content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Create the server
//app.use(ipfilter(ips, { mode: 'allow' }))

// simple route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Welcome to Server Application." });
});

require("./routes/customer.routes.js")(app);
require("./routes/data.routes.js")(app);

// set port, listen for requests
 app.listen(3002, () => {
  console.log("Server Connection Successful.");
  console.log("Server is running on port 3002.");
});
```

I have also set up the connection with Database Pooling thinking that might be the solution as per below:

```
const connection  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : dbConfig.CONNECTIONLIMIT,
  host            : dbConfig.HOST,
  user            : dbConfig.USER,
  password        : dbConfig.PASSWORD,
  database        : dbConfig.DB,
  port            : dbConfig.PORT
});
```

but the issue persists.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you hosting? Many cloud hosting providers turn down instances not in use (look up "cold start") to save resources. Some (all? not sure) providers have an option to keep a minimum number of instances running to prevent cold starts but this sounds like it's working as intended without more information.

Comment: Well that is not normal behaviour for node, and I would guess has nothing to do with node and is related to some other aspect of the environment. I would start trying to debug it by tracing your http requests and seeing where in the request-response cycle they are hanging.

Comment: I agree with others that this is not nodejs behavior.   This is something to do with the envrionment/system/network that your server is in.  You could instrument your code to see if the delay could be something to do with your database by logging when the request handler starts and when it finishes.  If there's a long difference between those, then perhaps it's the database that takes time to wake up.  If the request start time is just really late, then the problem is in the request getting to your Express server in the first place.

Comment: ok, i did some more research as per the above recommendations. I logged the request from React and the received response from Node then the database query. The request and received response is instant. Node running the query for the first time (after going to "sleep") takes the time from: sql.query(query, (err, res) => { to the response: if (res.length) { console.log("Received response from DB"); . This is where the delay is being generated. So seems like the Mysql has "gone to sleep"

Comment: Have posted a much more detailed and analyzed query at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64234583/mysql-with-node-js-initial-query-after-idle-takes-long-to-execute-subsequent-que Should this question be deleted?