# Mysql with Node.js initial query after idle takes long to execute subsequent queries are instant

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I am using React with Node.js for database interaction with Mysql 8. The database responds well, the application responds well and everything works as it is supposed to. However, if the site has been idle for about 5 minutes and a query is executed it would take close to a minute to return results. It does not matter what the query is or the amount of data returned, it could be 5 rows or 1000 rows, a query that previously returned instantly would return slowly if the site was inactive for 5 minutes.

The issue does not rest with the database, caching or table design. Node.js responds instantly when you log the interactions but pauses at the sql query (again, only the first time after idle).

Node.js creates a pool of 10 connections which are there and sitting idle. If Node.js is restarted (after 5 minutes of idle) the query again is instantaneous but I believe that is because Node.js has called the DB on startup and created the connection pool. The same events happens on both the development machine and the productions machine (even though the development machine is running an older version of Mysql then the production machine and has been set up differently from a caching, memory allocation etc. perspective). It is not a matter of the machine going to sleep mode as we are connected to it (dev machines and production machines).

If the site was idle for 5 minutes and the query is manually executed on Mysql Workbench, it is instantaneous but then utilizing the site again and the same query being executed and the response is slow then instant for any subsequent queries (or the same query).

After days and hours of interacting with all elements, I am confused as to where the issue would lie. Node.js responds quick until the query call, then slows down, any call thereafter is quick. Mysql Workbench manual query is always instantaneous. Restarting of Node.js server (after 5 minutes idle) would guarantee instant query.

Below is the configuration of my Node.js and example of a query call.

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const dbConfig = require("../config/DB.config.js");
const chalk = require('chalk');

const connection  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : dbConfig.CONNECTIONLIMIT,
  host            : dbConfig.HOST,
  user            : dbConfig.USER,
  password        : dbConfig.PASSWORD,
  database        : dbConfig.DB,
  port            : dbConfig.PORT
});

connection.getConnection((err, con) => {
  if (err) {
      if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
          console.error('Database connection was closed.');
      }
      if (err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR') {
          console.error('Database has too many connections.');
      }
      if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
          console.error('Database connection was refused.');
      }
  }
  if (con) con.release()
  return
})
```

Below is an example of the query called by one of the models:

```
Users.findByUserNameAndPassword = (username, password, result) => {
  console.log("HAVE ARRIVED AT THE MODEL, BEFORE QUERY");
  const query = `SELECT UserId as id from users WHERE Username = '${username}' `;

  sql.query(query, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      result(err, null);
      return;
    }

    if (res.length) {
      console.log("HAVE RECEIVED RESPONSE FROM DB");
.....
```

The log of "HAVE ARRIVED AT THE MODEL, BEFORE QUERY" is instantaneous all the time. The log of "HAVE RECEIVED RESPONSE FROM DB" is instantaneous unless the site was idle for 5 minutes.

I am not sure which element to focus on.

Comment: Is there any code after `if (res.length) { ..` ? If no, what happen if you change it into `else  {..` or `else if (res.length) { ...`?

Comment: yes there is code after the res.length that returns the result effectively. It is outside the scope as the pause happens before the res.length section.